# how to edit url path in javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url, path

i want to edit my URL path  of the current page and then redirect browser to the new path

for example i have this URL `https://example.com/about`

i want when i hit a button to take the current URL
and make `https://example.com/en/about`

so it will like this

```
var url      = window.location.href;  
// then edit it so it will be like 
// https://example.com/en/about

 window.location.replace(new_url);
```

and then how can i remove the **en** if i want to back the main url

how can i do this in pure Javascript or jQuery
or if there is a way to do it in php

thanks in advance ... <3

Comment: you can set the path using `window.location.href = "somepath.com";`

Comment: As you've tagged the question with PHP it would be ***far*** better to do this server side with .htaccess.

Comment: @Gunnarhawk i have a huge sitemap every url meet with another same url that had en in the url

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the problem is it not just one url its a lot urls

Comment: All the more reason to use .htaccess in that case.

Comment: If there is ANY type of pattern or predictability, .htaccess/mod_rewrite is the proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily break up `window.location` into its parts

This function allows you to pass a language in and changes the page location to that of the language at the same path

```
function ChangeLocation(lang) {
    window.location.href = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/" + lang + window.location.pathname;
}
```

With that being said, I would recommend you also look into `.htaccess` as there are a lot of people vouching for it in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Using `window.location.pathname` is best value to **search for** in *replacing* the url's path with what you want

```js
function replace_path_in_url_with(path) {
    var url = window.location.href.replace(window.location.pathname, "/"+path);
    window.location.replace(url);
}

replace_path_in_url_with("en/about");

// and if you want to go back just do 
replace_path_in_url_with("about");
```

Comment: A better answer includes more explanation of why the block of code you provide would work for this question.